# SQL : what is the canonical way to select a column from a table where another column is the maximum (or minimum) value?

Tags: sql

Consider a table with two columns, one being an integer primary key.

I want to select the row from the table with the maximum value of the primary key, then obtain the data from the other column of that row.

Here's how I currently do that:

```
select second_column 
from my_table
where first_column_pk =
        (select max(first_column_pk) from my_table);
```

Is this the canonical way to achieve this? Or is there a better and more efficient way?

This query involves two select statements. I don't know how to express the intention with a single select statement, but it seems like that might be possible.

I tried this, but it did not appear to work, because this is not a valid SQL syntax.

```
select second_column 
from my_table
where first_column_pk = max(first_column_pk)
```

I would prefer to do this with standard SQL, however I am using a Postgres database in this case, and it might be that Postgres supports some non-standard SQL which allows this.

Answer (score 1):

There is very rarely a "canon" way of doing anything in SQL - it's a declarative language, not imperative.

For your *specific* example, because you're using a unique key, you would simply do

```
select second_column
from my_table
order by first_column_pk desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: But in MSSQL this leads to the same execution plan as the statement in the question, and only a small change when using MySQL. Conclusion: both option are equal.

Comment: Okay... - so which is "canon"? As stated given the declarative nature, the query optimizer decides how to implement the query, there may, or may not be differences depending on a vast number of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of searching for it should be okay in the case of primary keys, but it might depend on the RDBMS and version. In general it's better to do it via

```
select second_column
from my_table
order by first_column_pk desc
limit 0, 1;
```

This orders your table by primary key and selects 1 element from offset 0, that is, the first element.